# Is there a way to preserve ControllerContext for asynchronous methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rotativa

I'm currently trying to make a very long method run asynchronously on my server. It takes several minutes so I don't want to have it all happen in one request. (I'm also using Azure App Services, which cuts off my connection after about 3.8 minutes, causing the Action to fail.) I want to have the first request from the user start an asynchronous method while subsequent requests and responses just check the status of the task. When the task is finished, I plan to send a file back to the user with all of the files the server has been creating through the async method.

However, I've run into a bit of a roadblock. We use the Rotativa library to generate pdf files from Razor pages and the method it uses to create these files requires us to pass in the ControllerContext. This works fine in synchronous situations, but the ControllerContext and some of its member objects are being disposed when the initial controller action finishes executing.

I've tried creating a new ActionContext using the ControllerContext as a construction parameter. I tried to serialize then de-serialize the ControllerContext, but it can't be serialized. Just passing the ControllerContext to a new variable fails as well, but I think that's to be expected in C#.

Does anyone know how to keep the ControllerContext or a copy of it and its member variables alive after the initial request is finished?

Comment: What happened when you constructed a new `ControllerContext` using the current `ActionContext`?

Comment: Use static variable will preserve it's data.

Comment: @MoB.I'll check tomorrow. I think some of the member objects were garbage collected because they were references to the objects in the original ControllerContext, but maybe I'm looking at it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Static can keep state of a variable. See bellow. In my second request, the variable already has the value from the first request.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out tomorrow and let you know how it goes.